# Xcode take huge amount of memory after SVN Update

Tags: ios, xcode, svn

I am developing for iPhone using Xcode I am experiencing a weird behavior every time I update my repository.
whenever I do that Xcode memory consumptions start to climb up to 60GB!!!!

- Trying to update directly from Xcode immediately starts the memory incline and it never reaches an end.
- Trying to update from finder does work but again the memory consumption starts clibing in xcode.
- Even closing xXcode does not help. The next time I open Xcode it starts accumulating memory until it reaches 60GB

The only solution I found for this is deleting the repository completely and checking it out again. 
This works until the next time I have to update the repository.

Has anyone encountered such a problem?
Any ideas as to how to solve this?

Thanks

Amit Raz

Comment: Check your bundle if you are adding any big framework or any external files which are big in size.

Comment: @ParasGorasiya I am not the only user. My friend has the exact same setup but it does not happen to him

Comment: @ParasGorasiya the Trunk folder is ~6GB and contains ~100K items

Comment: Examine the status line of Xcode while the build-up is happening. You are most likely indexing or doing something else expensive with the repo. Try letting it run.